# Spring Security - when to clear SecurityContextHolder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a controller and I'm returning user info from that controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
Object getUserInfo() {
    return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
}
```

I have created custom token based authentication using `OncePerRequestFilter`:

```
package gbyf;

import gbyf.token.Token;
import gbyf.token.TokenRepository;
import gbyf.user.User;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;

    TokenAuthenticationFilter(TokenRepository tokenRepository) {
        this.tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String tokenString = request.getHeader("token");

        if(tokenString == null) {
            // user is not authenticated, continue to filter
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        Token token = tokenRepository.findTokenByTokenValue(tokenString);

        if(token == null) {
            System.out.println("=====doFilterInternal()==== token is null, not authenticated");
        } else {

            System.out.println("=====doFilterInternal()==== token is NOT null");
            User user = token.getUser();

            if(user != null) {
                Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
                System.out.println("=====doFilterInternal()==== authenticated user");
            }
        }

        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    }

}
```

When I sent correct token parameter that found in database, it correctly authenticates the user. But with another `wrong` token request, server still sends old user authentication principals. Shouldn't SecurityContextHolder flush the authentication detail after request is done.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you using browser to call the API? If so, then I think session is being created for your user and being tracked via cookies. Try to use stateless session creation policy:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```